# Software or code for calculating automatically the propagation of uncertainty

Tags: error-propagation

When calculating the value of a variable that depends on the experimental values of other variables, $y=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, a usual way to calculate the standard error of that value is this one:

$$ \Delta y=\Delta f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Delta x_i)^2} $$

However, if the number of variables is big and the expression of $f$ long, the task of finding all the partials derivates, putting the experimental values and calculating the formula becomes extremely tedious. In addition, it could be that you are changing the data set, so that you have to calculate $\Delta y$ several times.

Is there any software that does this task automatically (derivating $f$ and computing the value of $\Delta f$)? Or maybe a Python code?

Comment: Then, I don't know where to place it: first I tried on the Physics forum, and there they said that it was also off-topic and suggested me to publish it here...